# How to set cookie in browser using restharp?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am using `restsharp` to authenticate to an external website. After that, I get your cookie.

How could I do to set this in the browser so that I stay logged in?

```
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic XXJhbmRvbTpyYW5kb20=");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

var cookie = client.CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(new Uri("http://www.example.com"));
```

Maybe there is no solution in C #, I'm thinking and returning by ajax and dealing with Javascript if it is possible.

Comment: What browser are you talking about? Embedded C# browser? Some external like Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Also please remove your base64-encoded header from code. It exposes your real password!

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: It's unclear to me how this code is used in context with Chrome.  Is this running in an Asp.Net application?

Comment: @Amy context is probably "on the same computer".

Comment: @Vyacheslav No, the context is "google chrome".  This could be an ASP.Net site for all we know.  The OP left out how he expects his c# code to interact with his browser.  Besides, that was a question only the OP can answer.

Comment: regardless of the browser I would like to be able to set the cookie on anyone

Comment: @EltonA.Pering Is this an ASP.Net application?  Regardless of which browser you're using, we still have no idea how your code expects to interact with *any* browser.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can set Google Chrome's cookies if your project type is ASP.Net-related.

If you're making a backend software just add new header to your response:

```
public void Test()
{
     Response.Cookies.Append("ExampleCookie", "Cookie value!");
}
```

#### You can't natively set Google Chrome's cookies from C# if browser is running side-to-side your application on one pc.

I don't really say you can't, but you really shouldn't do this. Because:

1) You need to find how cookies are stored in files
2) You need to modify them. Structures can change on any browser update.
3) It can trigger antivirus software. What if your application is trying to steal something from browser?

JavaScript only executes in the context of your page, it has access to internal API, so yes, it's much easier to do in JS.

You can use [embedded browser for WinForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser) or you can embed [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) browser (Chromium engine).
You can easily modify cookies of these browsers (that run in the context of your application).

Comment: You most certainly *can* if this is an Asp.Net application.

Comment: @Amy yes, you're probably right. Let me update my answer.